# remote deploy on tomcat with CARGO fails with TIMEOUT

Tags: tomcat, deployment, maven, timeout, maven-cargo

I'm running into a problem when doing a remote deploy with cargo-maven2-plugin (1.0.6). The war I'm deploying is rather large and the default 20 seconds are not enough to do the full deploy. 
The actual exception is (after 20 seconds):

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0.6:deploy (default-cli) on project myproject: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0.6:deploy failed: Failed to deploy [path/myproject.war]: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
```

I have cargo configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
<artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.6</version>
<configuration>
    <wait>true</wait>
    <container>
        <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
        <type>remote</type>
        <timeout>600000</timeout>
    </container>
    <configuration>
        <type>runtime</type> <!-- or remote -->
        <properties>
            <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>http://...:8080/manager/text</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
            <cargo.remote.username>...</cargo.remote.username>
            <cargo.remote.password>...</cargo.remote.password>
            <cargo.hostname>...</cargo.hostname>
            <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
            </properties>
    </configuration>

    <deployer>
        <type>remote</type> <!-- or installed -->
        <deployables>
            <deployable>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
                <properties>
                    <context>...</context>
                </properties>
                <pingURL>http://www.myProject.com:8080/</pingURL>
                <pingTimeout>25000</pingTimeout>
            </deployable>
        </deployables>
    </deployer>
</configuration>

<executions></executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Did you figure out the issue ? Even I got the same error.

Comment: You have set the [container timeout](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Container+Timeout) to 600s, but I think that only works for local containers. Your ping timeout is set to 25s - are you sure that deployment stops after 20 seconds? Did you try raising that parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be a case of [container timeout](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Container+Timeout).  Most likely, it is unable to connect to tomcat at the specified host and port.